# Make Javascript read and change time from inside symbol tag

Tags: javascript

Let me explain. There's going to be a file with lots of text, and it should hold timeouts. As seen below, when the user timer hits certain time, it changes text by reading time inside `<-- -->`.

`<-- 05m:06s--> 
      hello
<-- 05m:12s -->
      world!`

I do not ask for source code, or you to do it for me, i just would like to know is it possible  and some pointers to achieve this.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. Why don't you try putting more examples? Even pseudo-code could help :)

Comment: The text holds `<-- -->` tags. Inbetween them, there's time when it's started, so: if the timer hit's 05:06 (5 minutes and 6seconds), then it changes the text what's after the `<-- time -->` tag.

The text file has lots of them inside it, so i would need to make JS to read the text file.

Comment: A nice approach would be to use Ajax and let php to check the file and return data to javascript (which will take care of using that data).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is something to get you started. I choose to include the information mapping times to text inside `<li>` elements. Every time you update the timer, check for times in the `<li>` elements and if they match write their text.

http://jsfiddle.net/A3952/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="time"></div>
<div id="text"></div>

<div id="info">
    <ul>
        <li name="0h 0m 6s">something at 6s</li>
        <li name="0h 0m 8s">something at 8s</li>
        <li name="0h 0m 2s">something at 2s</li>
        <li name="0h 0m 10s">something at 10s</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    var startDate = new Date($.now());
    $('#time').html("0h 0m 0s");
    var secondCounter = 0;

    window.setInterval(function(){
        secondCounter ++;
        var timerStr = "";
        $('#time').html(Math.floor(secondCounter/3600)+"h "+ Math.floor(secondCounter/60)+"m " + secondCounter%60 + "s");

        $('#info ul li').each(function(event){
            if($('#time').html() == $(this).attr("name")){
                $('#text').html($(this).html());
            }
        });

    }, 1000);
});
```